# Changing preferences doesn't change SharedPreferences values

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I'm implementing preferences in my application and I've never worked with those before. I've read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) but I can't find a solution anywhere, I'm probably missing it though.

I've implemented preferences like this:

```
<CheckBoxPreference 
        android:title="@string/preference_update_urnik_title"
        android:summary="@string/preference_update_urnik_summary"
        android:key="autoUpdate"
        android:defaultValue="true"/>
```

and I basically haven't done anything else. I'm now trying to get the value of this preference like this:

```
boolean autoUpdate = prefs.getBoolean("autoUpdate", true);
```

And no matter if the checkbox is checked or not, it will always return true, so I'm guessing the preferences are failing to write to SharedPreferences when I check/uncheck the checkbox. Do I have to do it manually? Because I thought it was supposed to happen automatically.

I left the preference class file empty:

```
public class NastavitveActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you creating the prefs object? Is it a shared preferences object?

Comment: Shouldn't the SharedPreferences object be created when checkbox state is changed?

Comment: @Matthew Maybe you need to change the autoUpdate to autoupdate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Preferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
boolean value = preferences.getBoolean("autoUpdate", true);
```

this works for me.